# Bind mount one container FS tree into another for debug or ephemeral containers?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, mount, linux-kernel, namespaces

I'm testing out k8s debugging features including debug pods and ephemeral containers, and I just can't work out how to properly map a "target" pod's *file system* into the debug container.

I want to *link two disjoint mount namespaces with a recursive bind mount** so container A sees container B's root as `/containerB` or vice versa. Including all volumes and other mounts.

### Goal: Access to both debug and target container file systems at the same time

The goal is to have the target pod's *full filesystem tree, including volumes and other mounts* mapped to a subdir of the debug container e.g. `/run/target`. If the target container mounts persistent volumes, those mount points should be mapped, so e.g. if target container has `/data` then the debug container should have a mounted `/run/target/data`.

Alternately, it'd be ok to "inject" the debug container file system tree into the target container, so there's e.g. a `/run/debug` that exposes the debug container root available when `nsenter`ing the debug container. Including its mounts like procfs, so it's fully functional.

I want to be able to e.g. `gdb -p $target_pid` where `gdb` is provided by the debug container. `gdb` has to be able to find the process executables from the *target container* for this.

I've explored a few workaround approaches. But what I *really* want to do is `mount --rbind` the target container FS tree onto the guest or vice versa. Given a custom-built privileged debug container like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: debugcontainer
  namespace: default
spec:
  nodeName: TARGET_NODE_NAME_HERE
  enableServiceLinks: true
  hostIPC: true
  hostNetwork: true
  hostPID: true
  restartPolicy: Never
  containers:
  - image: DIAG_CONTAINER_IMAGE_HERE # you can experiment using something like ubuntu:20.04 
    name: debugger
    stdin: true
    tty: true
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /target
      name: target
    #- mountPath: /host
    #  mountPropagation: None
    #  name: host-root
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
      runAsGroup: 0
      runAsUser: 0
  volumes:
  - emptyDir: {}
    name: target
  #- hostPath:
  #    path: "/"
  #    type: ""
  #  name: host-root
```

where the debug container is launched into the *same node* as the target container, I can:

- See target container processes in `ps`
- attach to processes with `strace`, `gdb` etc because the privileged debug container has `CAP_SYS_PTRACE`
- `nsenter -t $some_target_container_pid --all` to "become" a proc in the target container, as if I'd done `kubectl exec`. I can no longer "see" or access the debug container files/tools.
- `nsenter -t $some_target_container_pid -m --root=/ --wd=/` to enter the target proc's mount namespace, but retain the privs of the debug container. I can no longer "see" or access the debug container files/tools.

But I cannot:

- See files in the target container at the same time as having access to the tools in the debug container - e.g. `gdb` can't find the executables being debugged
- See contents of volumes in the target container and apply debug container tools to them

Is there any recognised way to do this?

It's not totally k8s specific: the same issue applies with Docker, containerd, `runc`, etc.

You might expect this to be possible by using `mount --rbind` to "inject" the debug container into the target container via the host container namespace using a `hostPath` `volume` with `mountPropagation: Bidirectional`. But `containerd` mounts the container root image, *sets mount propagation to private* then mounts inner volumes. So the host mount namespace doesn't see the mounts made inside the container root image, and procs in the container don't see new mounts added by the host after the container's first process starts. See https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/mount_namespaces.7.html for details.

I've tried using `nsenter` to "cross" mount namespaces, but I can't get a bind mount to work. E.g. in the debug container I can

```
nsenter -t $some_target_container_pid --root=/ -m /bin/bash
```

which gives me a shell in which `.` (CWD) is the debug container rootfs, and `/` is the *target container* rootfs. But I can't seem to bind-mount them:

```
$ mkdir /run/debug
$ mount --rbind . /run/debug
mount: /run/debug: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on ., missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

The same occurs if I use `nsenter --wd=/` without `--root`, and try to `mount --rbind / ./run/debug`.

I've tried using `unshare -m` to create a new inner mount namespace first. And I've tried `mount --make-rprivate /` on the debug container tree before the bind mount. Same deal.

I can't work out why: there's nothing in dmesg and the error is very generic. I'm guessing it's due to the disjoint roots and/or disjoint mount namespaces. It doesn't seem to be due to the kernel's protection against bind mount circularity. And I'm using recursive binds, so it shouldn't be due to the protection against mount tree escapes in linux user namespaces.

An alterative to `--rbind`ing a FS tree would be if I had a way to `mount --bind` by *mount id* as shown in `/proc/$target_pid/mountinfo`. I could then clone all the mounts from the target pid into the debug container's mount namespace. But I can't `mount --bind` using a normal absolute path, because the target and debug container's mount namespaces are disjoint, and both have subtrees of mounts with private propagation.

I've tried using a target process's `/proc/$pid/ns/mnt` mount namespace, as I've seen reference to bind-mounting using it. But on my kernel 5.16 it's a tree of fake symlinks, not a fs tree:

```
$ readlink /proc/self/ns/mnt
mnt:[4026531840]
$ ls /proc/self/ns/mnt/
ls: cannot access '/proc/self/ns/mnt/': Not a directory
```

The closest thing I have to a workaround at the moment is the `nsenter` hack with the working directory. This offers very limited tooling injection into the target container. Where pid 1055 is a pid in the target container:

```
# nsenter -t 1055 -p -m --wd=/ /bin/bash
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory

# ls /
...target container rootfs contents here...

# ls .
...debug container rootfs here...

# ls ..
...debug container rootfs here too because . is a root...

# pwd
pwd: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory

# ls usr/bin/gdb
usr/bin/gdb

# ls /usr/bin/gdb
ls: cannot access '/usr/bin/gdb': No such file or directory
```

but I can't bind mount like I want, from within the same nsenter session:

```
# mkdir /run/debug
# mount --rbind . /run/debug
mount: /run/debug: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on ., missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

Hints?

---

Reference links:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/473717/45708
- https://medium.com/kokster/kubernetes-mount-propagation-5306c36a4a2d
- https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nsenter.1.html
- https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/user_namespaces.7.html
- https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/namespaces.7.html
- https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/unshare.1.html
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/594545/can-i-move-mount-to-other-mount-namespace
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/693822/bind-mount-across-namespaces-with-disjoint-roots

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use?

Comment: Container filesystems are visible to other containers in the pod through the `/proc/$pid/root`. This makes debugging easier, but it also means that filesystem secrets are protected only by filesystem permissions.  What is described in the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/share-process-namespace/#understanding-process-namespace-sharing).

Comment: So you could use: `kubectl debug -it <pod_name> --image=debian --share-processes=true --copy-to=debug --container=debug` than you can access volume attached to the first container via `/proc/$pid/root/path_to_thedirectory`. If is this solution suits for you let me know please

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak AFAICS from my testing `--copy-to` has "exciting" effects when the target has `initContainer`s or secondary containers. It also doesn't give you a privileged container with `CAP_SYS_PTRACE` and other privileges unless you make a custom manifest. I appreciate the pointer to `/proc/$pid/root` - it turns out you can't bind mount it, but you can use it as a symlink.

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak Also sorry I should've included the version. Bad dev no cookie. I'm on 1.21 but have also been testing with 1.22.

Comment: I've submitted a linux man-pages patch for the `mount_namespaces` docs to make this clearer in future. I also filed https://github.com/kubernetes/website/issues/32249 against k8s docs.

Answer (score 5):

It's possible to make a *symlink* to the target container's context via `/proc/${target_container_pid}/root`.

```
ln -s /proc/$pid/root /target
```

`/proc/$pid/root` *looks* like a symlink. If you `readlink /proc/$pid/root` it points to `/`. But it's the root of the target process, and if you dereference it *in the kernel vfs layer* you see the target process's root. If you resolve the symlink in userspace you will see the root of the processing doing the dereferencing.

I haven't been able to bind mount the tree - `mount -o bind /proc/$pid/root/ /target` will bind the rootfs of the `mount` process itself into `/target`, not the rootfs of the target process. But it doesn't matter much, as a symlink is sufficient.

(I'd write a patch for the `kubectl debug` documentation but I can't get my org to agree to the mandatory CLA required even for trivial docs patches...)

Comment: Thank you! I use this to launch `vim` installed on my docker host to `:Explore` the filesystem in containers without `vi` or `vim`.